# Repeating an input multiple times based on variable

Tags: python, variables, input, arithmetic-expressions

So I'm new to python and having a complete mental block as to how I can elegantly repeat this input for the product name based on the value of num_qc.

So for example if num_qc = 4
I would want the user to enter nam_prod1, nam_prod2 etc... 
As far as my understanding goes, I wouldnt want to pre-define these variables as the user could only enter 1 for num_qc or 50?

```
#report info
num_qc = input('Total QC open: ')
nam_prod = num_qc  * input('Name of unit %s: ' % num_qc)
```

Comment: Use a list or a dict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use a for loop or another [loop cycle](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) ,
what you want is:

```
num_qc = int(input('Total QC open: '))
for x in range(0,num_qc):
    nam_prod = input('Name of unit %s: ' % (x+1))
```

the name_prod variable will be overwritten with each cycle,
you can use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
num_qc = int(input('Total QC open: '))
nam_prod = []
for x in range(0,num_qc):
        nam_prod.append(input('Name of unit %s: ' % (x+1)))
```

Comment: I am needing to keep each variable so the second code block will keep the variable? I intend to write this information to a txt file or excel at the end of the program

Comment: of course, each data will have its own index in the list, with which you can read it (es. nam_prod[0], nam_prod[1], nam_prod[2], ....   ) 
you can use a loop cycle to read all the list.
look at the link to learn more about the lists https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!